# how to include external .C and .h file in AVR studio-4 project

Tags: avr, winavr

I am new in AVR world.i have found  a LCD file to use in my project. i have the .c and .h file to use. but i don't know how to include those file in my new project. Can any one give a relevant tutorial or example to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It a simple. Just copy the file into your project. And where you use this file, top of the project file just write `#include"your_file_name"`.

Comment: thanks bro. i have already copied all the file. but i did't included file in main file. thanks again.